# Azure DebugConsole - Can't upload more than 299 files

Tags: azure, file-upload

I am using Microsoft Azure for an WordPress website.

Recently, I created a folder in the root directory of my WordPress and I have to upload 4000 photos there.

Using the DebugConsole / Kudu I was able to create the folder and transfer the files but I noticed that only 299 files were transferred as shown here:

[image: As shown on this photo]

I tried to add the files again there but it won't work.

How can I upload the rest?

Comment: Which [price tier of Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/) are you using and what is the size of your files you want to upload?

Comment: @AaronChen for price tier i'm not sure as it's not mine but i have more than 15 websites there. As for filesize around 400mb of photos

Answer (score 0):

<del>Looks like you hit the disk space limit. You can check the usage of disk space via Kudu (`https://<your app name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/Env.cshtml`).</del>

---

Currently, there is a limitation of **299** files and directories we can view in Kudu. See [`Some folders are not visible in KUDU #2595`](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/2595). So, I'd recommend using the FTP client tool to connect to Azure and check exactly how many files were uploaded.

About how to connect to Azure App Service using FTP, please refer to:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-deploy-ftp

Another option is to use App Service Editor, which has fancier UI:

- `https://<your app name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/dev`

Comment: D:\home usage: 460,800 MB total; 444,571 MB free

d:\local usage: 230,397 MB total; 195,869 MB free

this is what i got....